# Can't send keys to element in one url but can in another - whats the catch?

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm using the package `RSelenium` in R to get some data from different sites.

The first site I've searched was https://www3.bcb.gov.br/expectativas/publico/consulta/serieestatisticas and it worked just fine (code to ilustrate):

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www3.bcb.gov.br/expectativas/publico/consulta/serieestatisticas")

indicador <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#indicador")
indicador$sendKeysToElement(list("Inflação acumulada para os próximos 12 meses"))
```

But in this other url it doesnt work:

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.ons.org.br/historico/carga_propria_de_energia.aspx")

indicador <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#passo1")
indicador$sendKeysToElement(list("SE/CO"))
```

it gets the following error:

> Summary: UnknownError
>
> Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>
> class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException

Why is that? I've looked the source code and the option name is apparently correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the element from `#passo1` to `#passo1 select`

Comment: thank you very much. But you know why is there this difference? is it because in the second url the option in element is already selected or something like that?

Comment: Not sure of the difference. I identified the css name of the particular variable using SelectorGadget extension in chrome.